# The norm of a separable Banach space can be determined by countable continuous linear functionals?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Recently I'm reading *Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions*, a result is used many times. It is

> *If $E$ is a separable Banach spaces, then there is a sequence $\{ \phi_n \}$ in its dual $E^{\star}$ such that $$\|x\|=\sup_n |\phi_n(x)|$$*

my question is

(1) How to prove it? Or where can I find the proof of it?

(2) Is there any other spaces that have this property? Where can I find related results?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For (1): Pick a countable dense set $x_i\in E$, and for each $x_i$ in that set, pick (by Hahn–Banach) a functional $\phi_i$ of norm $1$ such that $\|x_i\|=\phi_i(x_i)$.

For (2): duals of separable Banach spaces also have that property. For example, $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ is the dual of $L^1(\mathbb R)$ and its norm is therefore determined by countably many functionals.

Comment: A reference for this is e.g. "Functional Analysis and Semi-Groups" by Hille and Phillips, Theorem 2.8.5

Answer (score 2):

With respct to (2), we have the following result (Corolary 6.8 [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=pec4r3EsIiMC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22if+and+only+if+it+is+isometric+to+a+subspace+of%22&source=bl&ots=ONBIRG6Dbg&sig=tWDrLN6lgQGoh0o24Dv9anbB7J8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAWoVChMI6NHEmOT_yAIVSUOQCh1V-AVq#v=onepage&q=%22if%20and%20only%20if%20it%20is%20isometric%20to%20a%20subspace%20of%22&f=false)):

> A normed space have this property if and only if it is isometric to a subspace of $\ell_\infty$ .